# How to order collections in API Platform by foreign key?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a Symfony 6.2.6 application running on PHP 8.2. It uses API Platform.

How do I order collections in API Platform by foreign key?

---

#### Context

Consider following two entities - Offer and OfferProduct. An Offer can have multiple OfferProducts and they should be ordered by 2 columns:

- **OfferProduct.itemNo** - an integer
- **OfferProduct.parent** - a many to one relationship to OfferProduct

Here's the Offer.products declaration:

```php
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'offer', targetEntity: OfferProduct::class, cascade: ['persist'], orphanRemoval: true)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(['itemNo' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 'DESC'])]
#[Groups(['offer:index', 'offer:read'])]
private Collection $products;
```

---

#### What I want to accomplish

The order should provide a list of OfferProducts ordered by itemNo, then for matching itemNos the OfferProducts with NULL parents should be first.

---

#### What happens in the above example

The annotations work perfectly fine in the rest of the Symfony application.However, API Platform throws an error when reading the Offer resource in an offer:read context:  **"Warning: Undefined array key "parent"**.

According to the stack-trace, the error stems from ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\ReadListener.

However, the parent key is provided in the offer:read serialization context:

```php
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: self::class, inversedBy: 'extras')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete: 'CASCADE')]
#[ORM\OrderBy(['id' => 'DESC'])]
#[Groups(['offer:read'])]
#[ApiPlatform\ApiProperty(readableLink: false, writableLink: false)]
private ?self $parent = null;
```

I've also tried changing the "parent" key in OrderBy to "parentId", which results in the same error.

---

**Is there a way to accomplish this in a clean manner?** Or do I have to resort to sorting the list either client-side or in application logic prior to returning the data?

Thanks in advance for your help!